# How do I make an animated choropleth in plotly where in the first frame it shows data from my column hunger_index and in the second frame food_waste?

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

This is how my example df named test could look like.

| country | code | hunger_index | food_waste |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Angola | ANG | 20 | 10 |
| Russia | RUS | 4 | 18 |
| Cuba | CUB | 7 | 20 |
| Armenia | ARM | 4 | 16 |

This is my current code:

```
fig = px.choropleth(test,
                    locationmode='country names',
                    locations='country',
                    color=['hunger index', 'food waste'],
                    hover_name='country',
                    projection='natural earth',
                    animation_frame=['hunger index', 'food waste'],
                    title='Global Inequality',
                    color_continuous_scale='Reds')
fig.show()
```

I tried to run it like this but I get this error:
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `animation_frame` is 2, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['country'] is 4

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Choropleth plots can visualize only one variable as a color scale. Either you use the `'hunger index'` or `'food waste'`. Can you share an example of the plot you want to produce?